# How to set the Initial viewController in AppDelegate Programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I know that this question was asked a couple of times but I tried all the solutions and nothing really worked for me.

I am currently working on an iOS Project and encountered a problem.

I am building an App which needs some personal information at the first launch. Therefore I use a `NavigationController` which I set to be the `Initial View Controller` in Storyboard.

Now I would like to check in my AppDelegate whether the User already entered the Personal Data. In this case I created a `User Defaults KV Pair called "onboarding" of type Bool`

If the Value is `true`, I would like to change the Initial View Controller to the main `TabBarController`, the rest of the App uses.

I hope this image can illustrate what I meant above:
[image]

I hope you can think of a way to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance. Have a great day!

Comment: This has been asked more than "a couple of times". It has been asked and answered _hundreds_ of times. No existing answer will be something you can just copy and paste directly and use, because your needs may be slightly different. But all of them are _principles_ you can learn from and apply to achieve your goals. — Just to add to the mix, here's my (downloadable) example: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample/blob/master/RegistrationExample/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: are you using swiftui or scenedelegate in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open your **AppDelegate.swift** and add property

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

2) In

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

a) initialize this window:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

b) set UIViewController you needed to `window`'s **rootViewController** property:

```
window?.rootViewController = myViewController
```

c) make this window key and visible:

```
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

That is all.
And don't forget to remove your storyboard from target settings:
[Remove storyboard from target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlIUs.png)

Hope its help.

Comment: Is this also working with UITabBar and UINavigationController instead of a UIViewController?

Comment: @Chri2000R UITabBarController and UINavigationController _are_ UIViewControllers. Do you know about classes and subclasses?

Comment: Yes, sure. But UITabBarController, not UITabBar :)